# Download install app from Instant Application

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I implemented an instant app in separate project from installed app and its same as:

- application id
- key release
- version code in the instant app is always smaller than the installed app

I using showInstallPrompt to display dialog download from instant app to download full app.

```
  Intent postInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            .setPackage(getApplication().getPackageName());

    // The request code is passed to startActivityForResult().
    InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(this,
            postInstall, 101, "InstantApp");
```

When I tap on download button in InstallPrompt dialog, I got the error:

```
you cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device
```

p/s: I uploaded all Appbundle in Play Store for internal testing for both the install and instant app.

Does anyone have the same as this issue and any advice for this case? Thanks!

Comment: Please ignore my question because the issues come when I'm checking in Internal Testing. When prompt it to production, it works well with no more issues.